# Swift UTF8 encoding and non UTF8 character

Tags: swift, string, utf-8

I've a some text from json file. In this text I've applied UTF8 encode but this encoder don't recognize a non standard character `àèìòù` and it's capital char, is there a method to purify my string?

My function:

```
func stringToUTF8String (stringaDaConvertire stringa: String) -> String {
    let encodedData = stringa.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let attributedOptions = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType]
    let attributedString = NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil, error: nil)!
    //println(attributedString.string)
    return attributedString.string
}
```

Comment: What byte output is `String` giving you? What would you expect? Also I'm not sure your insertion of the non-standard character into StackOverflow went correctly.

Comment: Please show a (short) input string demonstrating the problem together with the actual output and the expected output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found a solution.

The UTF8 take 8 bit of table ASCII, and the UTF16 take 16 bit ASCII table, the solution is simple by modifying my function to:

```
func stringToUTF16String (stringaDaConvertire stringa: String) -> String {
    let encodedData = stringa.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF16StringEncoding)!
    let attributedOptions = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType]
    let attributedString = NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil, error: nil)!
    //println(attributedString.string)
    return attributedString.string
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but I still don't know why dataUsingEncoding is not able to identify the character using UTF8StringEncoding. In my case, I verified my file is stored as UTF-8, so `encodedData` should contain the right content, my guess is that NSAttributedString uses UTF-16 encoding, after all that is the only encoding supported by NSString, the documentation is not clear about this though.

Comment: I was having the same problem and worked out it must be due to `NSAttributedString`. The documentation never specify what encoding the parameter `data` should have, but I think we have verified that it MUST be `NSUTF16StringEncoding`. Internally they probably decode with that.

Comment: The foundational `NSString` is represented using UTF-16, so that default would make sense. That being said, you can specify `options: [characterEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]` to match the incoming data.