# Swift JSON Encode error iOS

Tags: ios, json, encoding

I tried a lot to figure out why my app cannot encode the `German` letters like `ä`,`ö`. I have created a `mysql` database in which I set all the the table fields to `UTF-8 Unicode` and also the Collation to `utf8_unicode_ci`. Then I created a `php` file that returns some results from the database. Now I am testing with my `localhost` the `Json` format and the results are fine, I mean that my response encodes correctly the `German` letters. And for my `iOS` app I do the following:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8888/Database/test.php")
let allDataString = String(contentsOfURL: url!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
let utfData = allDataString!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
var allProducts: AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(utfData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(0), error: nil)
```

And for example my response is like:

```
"food_description" = "Schafk&auml;se mit Zwiebeln, Oliven&ouml;l und Oregano";
```

Can you please suggest me how to solve this?

Comment: maybe using `html_entity_decode()` to decode the html entities `&…;` to the UTF-8 equivalents on the `php` side is preferable

Comment: @vadian thank you for your suggestion. I will test it and i will report back. The strange think is that in my browser the results are normal.

Comment: the browser usually decodes the html entities implicitly. Try to figure out where the entities are created. Maybe they are already be written into the database.

Comment: @vadian I already use this `html_entity_decode()` and does the work for the browser. For now i found a solution from the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27849966/swift-utf8-encoding-and-non-utf8-character. Maybe the problem comes from my db. I don't really know.